# Is there a best directory to place image uploads on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave and I want to change the directory where images are stored.

Right now the image URL is /uploads/modelname/image/51/nameoffile.jpg

the store_dir in ImageUploader is

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

I definitely do not want the modelname to show
Is there an accepted ideal path where images should be stored on heroku?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku doesn't allow uploads to their servers.  You need to use another storage medium, like Amazon's S3.

I'm actually using Parse's (www.parse.com) API to store images on their solution.  But it depends how you need access to your images.

Comment: Heroku also charges for data that passes through their dynos (over a certain amount, anyway).  Look for a storage solution that will allow your uploads to bypass their servers, or use a Heroku dyno on EC2-east and use S3; transfers are free between the two.  Very-low-usage (dev level) S3 is free, too, and the prices scale nicely from there.

Comment: thanks, I will open up an Amazon S3 account. Is there a good conventional and safe path to use though? The images are uploaded by users with their posts so that's the only type of access I need. It will also be very low usage at the moment as I don't have any users

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files to the Heroku dyno filesystems but the filesystem are perishable and not shared among your dynos. Here's a Gist showing how to make Carrierwave store uploaded file in AWS S3 which is a better option: https://gist.github.com/cblunt/1303386

Here's a Heroku guide for accomplishing this with PaperClip: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3