# Heroku where can i save files?

Tags: database, heroku

I have a telegram bot, and it saves the user's audio messages and photos in the repository and DB(path only), I deployed it in on pythonanywhere and everything works.

But before that, I tried to deploy it on heroku and ran into the problem that you can't store files there and everything can only be done through databases.

Do I understand correctly that you need to create a field in the database that stores the file itself, or are there other ways?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a best directory to place image uploads on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438897/is-there-a-best-directory-to-place-image-uploads-on-heroku)

Comment: partially, as far as i understand either I save directly to the database or I use third party storage

Comment: I wouldn't recommend cramming files directly into your database, but yes, something like Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage would be a reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

You may use, for example, [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/). They provide 25GB of bandwidth for free. The service is intended to be used for pictures but works well with other files as well. AND it has a good API to go with it for many programming languages (not sponsored)).